# can't receive file with multer (node.js-nuxt3)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, multer, nuxtjs3

I use nuxt3/node.js with [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer.) ,
i can't store or receive file in my server and i can't see req.file in root, its empty all time.
server Code:

```
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' })
router.post('/sendNewQuestionCSV', upload.single('csv'),adminControler.sendNewQuestionCSV.bind(adminControler))
```

and my FrontEnd Code with nuxt3:

```
async function fileSelected(e) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("csv", e.target.files[0]);
  const res = await $postFetch("/admin/sendNewQuestionCSV", formData, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
  });
}
```

note:$postFetch is an method i made my self use fetch and third argument is "headers". its a nuxt3 Plugin

this Plugin code:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async () => {
  return {
    provide: {
      postFetch: async (url, body,headers={}) => {
        let token = useCookie('token');
        return await $fetch(url, {
          method: 'post',
          body: { token: token.value, ...body },
          baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().API_BASE,
          ...headers
        }).catch((error) => error.data)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) to add the `token`:

```
  postFetch: async (url, body,headers={}) => {
    let token = useCookie('token');
    body.append('token', token.value);
    return await $fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      body: body,
      baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().API_BASE
    }).catch((error) => error.data)
  }
```

**EDIT**

also try removing `headers`

Comment: its not about token

Comment: toke works good and auth working server side

Comment: @Ezioadf2 did you try the code?

Comment: yes,it had error, im sure problem is from front end because it worked with postman

Comment: @Ezioadf2 what error. the problem is that you should use append instead of spread operator on form, this way only token is sent, not the file

Comment: let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("csv", e.target.files[0]);
  let token = useCookie("token");
  formData.append("token", token);
  await $fetch('/admin/sendNewQuestionCSV', {
    method: "post",
    body: formData,
    baseURL: useRuntimeConfig().API_BASE,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });

Comment: i used it directly and had same result

Comment: @Ezioadf2 try removing `headers`, try the updated code

Comment: it worked,it happen when nuxt.js has bad docs, in nuxt 2 we needed it set it but nuxt 3 no need, it made me angry and taken from me more than 8 hours